# Wordpress: how to track a short code source

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-shortcode

I'm improving a theme that wasn't created by me. On one of the sections there is a short code (which is prod_category). I would like to track it down so I can add/remove products from which list this short code refers to, but how can I track it down?

Thanks in advance

Comment: to track a short code source, I would first look for it in the theme's functions file. Then if not there, I would make a search through all files of my theme of all instances of the shortcode it self "prod_category"

Comment: Thanks a lot Gael that's exactly what I did now, I downloaded the whole theme and looked for the short code

Comment: I see only 2 options: create a child theme and edit manually the shorcode function in the theme code, or use a combination of `remove_shortcode()` and `add_shortcode()` in your functions.php to redefine completely the shortcode behaviour (you can use the theme function as a base). You can also use the `shortcode_exists()` function before remove for a more versatile code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search the shortcode in all theme source with a code editor, if nothing is finded search in the plugin folder.

The function to create a new shortcode is this:

```
// [mycustomshortcode foo="foo-value"]
function mycustomshortcode_function( $atts ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'foo' => 'something',
        'bar' => 'something else',
    ), $atts ) );

    return "foo = {$foo}";
}
add_shortcode( 'mycustomshortcode', 'mycustomshortcode_function' );
```

In this case you have to search mycustomshortcode